# Angular 2 ngfor animation one item

Tags: angular, animation, ngfor

I couldn't find answer to this question anywhere, please help. If i have the following code:

```
<div *ngFor="let task of tasks; let i = index">
    <div>
        <a (click)="slide()" md-icon-button>
            <md-icon [@rotateArrow]="arrow">details</md-icon>
        </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

function `slide()` changes `arrow` from `down` to `up` and vice versa, and the animation works great, but it is applied to all the `md-icon` elements of the `ngFor` loop. My goal is to animate only that one single `md-icon` that was clicked on. How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can have `task.arrow` property

Comment: Ok, yurzui, I understand how to change the value of the single element inside the array, but how to do the animation on a single item?

Comment: You should create a task-component, so every task-component whould have it's own arrow property.

Comment: Yes, I eventually did it that way. Thank you both.